# Binding delimited strings in textbox to Collection<String>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have an `<form:input type="text" />` element that can take several values, each delimited by a semicolon.  For example, it can take a value such as `Mike;Jack;Bob`.

How can I bind/pass this type of value for an `<input>` to a `Collection<String>` in Spring 3 MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a property editor:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Collection.class, 
          new DelimitedCollectionStringEditor());
}
```

where the editor must extend `PropertyEditorSupport`